# How and why does golang scheduler recursively run goroutines in runtime/proc.go:execute?

Tags: go, programming-languages

I'm trying to break down how the Go scheduler works, and what I'm seeing in [runtime/proc.go](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/6b3bb4ba3bcc190200af4f1eedf454658094097f/src/runtime/proc.go#L2177) is:

1. The `schedule` function calls `execute` to run a goroutine
2. The comment for `execute` explicitly says this function never returns. It calls `gogo` function defined in one of the assembly files.
3. The `gogo` function performs a jump to the address of the first instruction of a new goroutine.
4. After this goroutine is completed, the `schedule` function is called again, so we're back to step 1.

If my understanding is correct, then how does this scheme avoid stack overflow? 
Does it have something to do with "infinite" stacks that automatically increase their size, or am I missing something here?

Comment: What do you mean by "goroutines within each other"? All goroutines run independent from each other, there is no nesting. Also, jumping to a new goroutine involves switching the stack. Each goroutine has its own stack.

Comment: You're right, the "within each other" part doesn't make sense, they run independently.
However, when a goroutine completes, the "schedule" function is called again, which will run another goroutine (which may be completely unrelated to the previous one), so the process is recursive.

Comment: The process is not recursive, because the stack is different between invocations of `schedule`. The stack on entry to `schedule` is different from the stack after it jumps to the new goroutine.

Comment: While it might be an interesting academic exercise to understand the scheduler, it is *not* helpful to new developers to think they can second-guess it. The language specification and memory model should be sufficient documentation. Provided the behaviour of programs that use goroutines isn't affected,  this allows the Go developers to rewrite details of the scheduler as often as they like,

Comment: @Rick-777 sure, I understand that. I'm only doing it as an exercise and out of curiosity.

Comment: Cool, just need to avoid suggesting to newbies that they ought to attempt something inadvisable. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I spent some time researching the subject and can now try to answer my own question. The whole goroutine lifecycle turned out to be a bit more complex:

1. New goroutines are created in a special goroutine called `g0`, which is kind of a main goroutine of a thread. Any call to `go func` changes the stack from whatever current goroutine it was called from to `g0` (this is done in `proc.go:newproc`).
2. When the goroutine is created (in `proc.go:newproc1`), its stack (and/or program counter, PC) is constructed in a way that it *looks* like it was called by `goexit` function. This is done to guarantee that when goroutine completes and returns, it is  returned to `goexit`.
3. When `schedule` is called and a goroutine is chosen to run, the `execute` function executes it (== jumps to its address via the `gogo` assembly function).
4. After the goroutine has completed, it *returns* to `goexit` function, implemented in assembly.
5. That assembly function calls `proc.go:goexit1` (not sure why this extra step in assembly is needed).
6. The `goexit1` function changes current stack to `g0`. This is done with a call to `mcall` ("Machine thread call"), which executes whatever function is received in an argument. In this case the function supplied to `mcall` is `goexit0`.
7. The `mcall`, implemented in assembly, jumps to the address of `g0`'s stack frame (SP) and performs a `CALL` to `goexit0`.
8. The `goexit0` function is executed in the context of `g0`. It puts a completed goroutine on a list of free goroutines, and frees its stack if it was previously increased.
9. Then `goexit0` calls `schedule` again, which chooses a goroutine to run, so we get back to step 3.

So indeed there seems to be no recursion here. The scheduled goroutine itself never calls `schedule`: this is done by a special goroutine `g0`.
I'm still not sure if I captured all the details though, so comments and additional answers are appreciated.